# Converting a string to a set to compare with another set

Tags: python, string, set

I have a csv called data that looks like this (but with a few hundred records):

```
Id     Value
1k     {'asadf', 'copklj', 'glkjkj', 'hsijlk'}
2j     {'boilk', 'dljk', 'aasadf'}
6k     {'eljkj', 'tljkjlk', 'jljlij'}
```

I would like to iterate through each row to see if the value (2nd column) in that row matches or is a superset of another set that I have. To do this, I pulled the Value for each row using the following code:

```
i = 1
x = data['Value'].iloc[i]
```

I planned on using this in a loop that would add 1 to the variable `i` each time it iterated. However whenever I did `type(x)` it came out as `str`. To change this so that I could compare it to my other set, I did both

```
x = set(x)
```

and

```
x = set([x])
```

The first one comes out with all the letters split apart. The second one comes out with

```
{"{'asadf', 'copklj', 'glkjkj', 'hsijlk'}"}
```

The output that I would like is

```
{'asadf', 'copklj', 'glkjkj', 'hsijlk'}
```

so that I can compare this set and the other set I have. How can I change my code to do that?

Comment: Is column `Value` actual `set` objects? What does `df.Value.map(type)` show you?

Comment: Judging by the reported output of `set(x)`, your `x` is a string, not a set.

Comment: @JonClements it comes back with `str`. but when it was written to the csv before, it had been a `set`

Comment: CSV files do not support sets. You can only store strings or string representations of numbers in CSV files.

Comment: @DYZ so I have to change it before I do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading your CSV file, use a converter to make it a set again, then apply a subset operation, eg:

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('somefile', converters={'Value': ast.literal_eval})
is_subset = df.Value.map({'a', 'b'}.issubset)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you saved your data into a CSV file, your sets were converted into strings because CSV files do not support sets. You can convert the strings back to sets with `ast`:

```
import ast
df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```